# jQuery - Constant Repeat Animation timesout page

Tags: jquery

I have the following:-

HTML:

```
<span id="flare-1" class="space-flare"></span>
<span id="flare-2" class="space-flare"></span>
```

jQuery:

```
// Animate Stars

jQuery(function() {
    var star = jQuery("#flare-1"), degree = 0, timer;
    var star2 = jQuery("#flare-2"), degree = 0, timer;
    rotate();
    function rotate() {

        star.css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});  
        star.css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});  
        star2.css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});  
        star2.css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});                      
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            ++degree; rotate();
        },8);
        setTimeout(function(){
            setInterval(function () {
               star.fadeIn(500).delay(100).fadeOut(1000).delay(4000).fadeIn(1000);
            }, 500);
        },5000); 
        setTimeout(function(){
            setInterval(function () {
               star2.fadeIn(500).delay(100).fadeOut(1000).delay(4000).fadeIn(1000);
            }, 500);
        },3000); 
    }
});
```

Which animated two different stars at different intervals. If I leave the page open for about 2 minutes the website the browser times out saying 'something went wrong when displaying this page'.

Also, the animations gradually get slower and slower and I'm not sure why, I think this could be related to the problem.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Here is my [jSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/o9etyqgo/)

Comment: Add `HTML` also in your question to make it more clear. You can also make a Fiddle.

Comment: @Manwal I've added these :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Everytime* you call `rotate()` (every 8ms) you start a new `setTimeout`, which starts a new `setInterval`.

After just 3 seconds, the first 375 timeouts will hit, which will start 375 intervals.

I recommend hooking into `setTimeout` and `setInterval` to show just how many times this is being called:

```
window.originalSetTimeout=window.setTimeout;
window.originalSetInterval=window.setInterval;

window.setTimeout=function(func,delay)
{
    console.log("setTimeout");
    return window.originalSetTimeout(func, delay);
};

window.setInterval=function(func,delay)
{
    console.log("setInterval");
    return window.originalSetInterval(func, delay);
};
```

You probably want to move the fadeIn/fadeOut code outside rotate():

```
var star = jQuery("#flare-1");
var star2 = jQuery("#flare-2");
var degree = 0;

rotate();

function rotate() {
    star.css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});  
    star.css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});  
    star2.css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});  
    star2.css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});                      
}

setInterval(function() {
    ++degree; 
    rotate();
}, 8);

setTimeout(function(){
    setInterval(function () {
       star.fadeIn(500).delay(100).fadeOut(1000).delay(4000).fadeIn(1000);
    }, 500);
}, 5000); 

setTimeout(function(){
    setInterval(function () {
       star2.fadeIn(500).delay(100).fadeOut(1000).delay(4000).fadeIn(1000);
    }, 500);
}, 3000);
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o9etyqgo/1/

Comment: Thanks for explaining this so well :) working perfectly now.